# Send data between page and modal dialog in Blazored

Tags: c#, modal-dialog, blazor, blazored

I have a page that lists some data in a table, in the last column I have created a

```
<td>
  <a class="nav-link" href="Edit/@item.id">
   <span class="oi oi-pencil" aria-hidden="true">Edit</span>
  </a>
</td>
```

That open the `Edit` page, and send the `id` with it. Recently, I found **Balzored** library which allow creating modal (pop up like) dialogs.

If I need to open a page, I would

```
<NavLink class="nav-link" @onclick="@(()=>modal.Show<Create>("Create"))">
   Add New
</NavLink>
```

But how can I pass the *@item.id* to the **Edit** page in `Blazored`.

The **Edit** page has `@page "/edit/{Id}"` as the first line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I would not make the modal a page, make it a component. That is the beauty of Blazor. In that modal, you would add a parameter. It could be the id and you could go look it up again, or you could just pass the entire item you want to edit:

Your "Edit" modal should have something like this, and no @page directive - just make it a component:

```
[CascadingParameter] BlazoredModalInstance BlazoredModal { get; set; } = default!;
[Parameter] public int ItemId { get; set; }
```

In the main page that holds the table, create a method to handle the click and open the modal:

```
private async Task OnEditItemAsync(int ItemId)
{
    var parameters = new ModalParameters()
        .Add(nameof(Create.Id), ItemId);
    Modal.Show<Create>("Modal Title", parameters);
    // Add code to handle the modal result or refresh the table
    StateHasChanged();
}
```

In your table column, add a button that calls the method:

```
<td>
    <button onclick="@(async () => await OnEditItemAsync(item.Id))">Edit</button>
</td>
```

https://blazored.github.io/Modal/usage/passing-data

Comment: Thank you for your effort but I am getting null instead of the Edit page.

Comment: Did you setup a handler method? Personally, I would put a button in the column and then do an `onclick`. I will add it to my answer.

Comment: Yes, the problem was the href, it gives null with the button it worked. Thanks.